# I create my first app in reactjs with expo CLI and got this error when try to start it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

E:\Reactjs>npm start

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path E:\Reactjs\package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Reactjs\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Armando Sanchez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-01T16_24_18_297Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`npm start` is not required to run Expo projects.

Here are few important commands for **Expo**

To create Expo Project:  `expo init PROJECT_NAME`

To run Expo Project:  `expo start`

To clear cache of Expo Project:  `expo r -c`

To install all libraries mentioned in package.json: `npm install` or `yarn install`